# DateTime AddYears() Array not working as expected

Tags: c#, arrays, datetime

I have a problem with the dates. I cant get the `.AddYears()` method to work. Can somebody please have a look on what I am doing wrong here.

```
MySqlConnection myMySqlConnection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter();
MySqlCommand cmd1;
cmd1 = new MySqlCommand("SELECT INITIAL_DATE FROM USERS WHERE ID = @id1", myMySqlConnection);
cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id1", id);
myMySqlConnection.Open();
da.SelectCommand = cmd1;
DateTime initial_date = (DateTime)cmd1.ExecuteScalar();
myMySqlConnection.Close();
```

From this point and below is the problem:

```
DateTime[] dates = new DateTime[20];
dates[0] = Convert.ToDateTime(initial_date);

for (int i = 1; i < 20; i++)
{
     dates[i] = initial_date.AddYears(1);
}
```

Comment: What is happening when you run this code?

Comment: Don't you want `dates[i] = initial_date.AddYears(i);` so you don't have datetimes 1->20 as the same date?  Is this the problem you are experiencing?  BTW, DateTime is immutable, so any methods you run on it to create a new DateTime will return a new instance of DateTime, not alter the one you execute the method on.

Comment: The first value selected from the database is 1/20/2012 and i want an array that will contain the values 1/20/2012, 1/20/2013, 1/20/2014.... and so forth and will continue for 20 years. The last value (dates[19]) must be 1/20/2032

Comment: Then in addition to my suggestion, you need to make your DateTime array length 21 and change your for condition to `i <= 20` as your current code will only create 20 values, whereas you want 21.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `initial_date.AddYears(1);` was repeatedly adding 1 to the same value so all DateTimes after the initial one were of the same value.  DateTime is immutable, so calls to its methods do not change its value, but return a new instance with the desired value.  You need to change it to `initial_date.AddYears(i);`
2. If you want the range of years to be 2012 - 2032 you actually need 21 values, not 20 - so you'll need to adjust your array length and for loop condition accordingly

Change your problem code to:

```
DateTime[] dates = new DateTime[21];
dates[0] = Convert.ToDateTime(initial_date);

for (int i = 1; i <= 20; i++)
{
     dates[i] = initial_date.AddYears(i);
}
```

It will give you the results you need.

Comment: 1+ your comment worth more than answer

Answer (score 1):

As Mark M pointed out, your problem probably lies in your adding `1`, rather than `i`, through the `AddYears` method within the for loop.

Here’s the corrected code in LINQ:

```
DateTime[] dates = Enumerable.Range(0, 20).Select(initial_date.AddYears).ToArray();
```

Comment: thank you very much for the linq code but i am not using linq for the moment

Answer (score 0):

I would simplify the code slightly, and as Mark M says in his comment, replace the `1` in `AddYears` by `i`

```
DateTime[] dates = new DateTime[20];
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    dates[i] = initial_date.AddYears(i);
}
```

Comment: OMG you are completely right, i am so sorry for the fuss... my mistake

Answer (score 0):

If your intent is to set up an array having different years, then you'll want to `AddYears(i)` instead of only adding 1 year

```
DateTime initial_date = DateTime.Now;
DateTime[] dates = new DateTime[20];
dates[0] = Convert.ToDateTime(initial_date);

for (int i = 1; i < 20; i++)
{
    dates[i] = initial_date.AddYears(i);
    Console.WriteLine(dates[i]);
}
```

That will print out:

6/2/2013 12:01:48 PM

6/2/2014 12:01:48 PM

6/2/2015 12:01:48 PM

6/2/2016 12:01:48 PM

6/2/2017 12:01:48 PM

6/2/2018 12:01:48 PM

6/2/2019 12:01:48 PM

6/2/2020 12:01:48 PM

6/2/2021 12:01:48 PM

6/2/2022 12:01:48 PM

6/2/2023 12:01:48 PM

6/2/2024 12:01:48 PM

6/2/2025 12:01:48 PM

6/2/2026 12:01:48 PM

6/2/2027 12:01:48 PM

6/2/2028 12:01:48 PM

6/2/2029 12:01:48 PM

6/2/2030 12:01:48 PM

6/2/2031 12:01:48 PM